# Assembly.LoadFile raises Assembly resolve event on same Assembly

Tags: c#, .net-assembly

In one of our applications we had a custom Assembly Resolve event that looks like below.
While far from perfect, this worked OK (meaning: good enough) in our application when we were targeting NET FX 4.6.2

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += (sender, args) =>
{
    string fileName = args.Name.Split(',').FirstOrDefault();

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName))
    {
        fileName += ".dll";

        FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);

        string filePath = null;

        //If block should just make sure that filePath is set to an existing file...
        //left it in in case I misread something in there...
        if (fileInfo.Directory != null)
        {
            filePath = Path.Combine(fileInfo.Directory.FullName, fileName);
            if (!File.Exists(filePath))
            {
                filePath = Path.Combine(standardAddInsDirectory, fileName);
                if (!File.Exists(filePath))
                {
                    filePath = Path.Combine(customerAddInsDirectory, fileName);
                    if (!File.Exists(filePath))
                    {
                        filePath = null;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        //at this point filePath should be either null OR the full path to the dll

        Assembly assembly = null;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filePath))
        {
            assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(filePath); //this line raised AssemblyResolve again
        }
        return assembly;
    }
    return null;
};
```

However, we had to update to 4.8, and once there, we got a stackoverflow exception because Assembly.Load(path) did raise an assembly resolve event for the exact same assembly we did try to load.
The exact case that brought our code down was "Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives 3.0.0.0", but we only shipped version 2.2.
We did call Assembly.Load on the 2.2 version and the event was raised again for the same assembly / version ("Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives 3.0.0.0").

I wanted to write a small MVS / Testcase afterwards but was not able to - I could not figure out how to declare an assembly (or a dependency) so that I came into the same situation.
I used strong naming, version mismatches, dependcies,...but to no luck.

Could you please help with the following two questions:

1. Did the assembly load / Assembly Load Event handling change with
   4.8 OR could this have been an issue with differently restored nuget packages?
2. How can I build assemblies to force such behavior and have a testcase for it?

Comment: Seems to me assembly resolve will trigger for each dependency as well.... Also why are you using Assembly resolve? Why not let .NET do the work? Finally have you tried Assembly Redirection?

Comment: It is triggered with AssemblyResolveEventArgs pointing to the same assembly again, not a dependent one.

Regarding why we're doing it on our own: A (maybe too) enterprisey application that can load addins from addin directories AND tries to make assembly mapping a bit easier (f.e. not needing to update 100s of appconfig redirects when f.e. newtonsoft.json is updated)

Comment: I would not understand why you would need 100s of redirects... most likely you would only needed in your entry point projects... But to load "add-ins" you do not need to handle every single assembly's resolution.    If all you want is to load "add-ins" then limit your resolution logic to those assemblies and let .NET do the rest.

Comment: Also I would use LoadFrom rather then LoadFile... they are not the same.  LoadFrom will work better when the same dependency is trying load several times.

Comment: All in all it's around 20 services (layered with some service dependencies within - hence the update problem) with around 400 projects and 200 unit test projects. Each unit test project is a startup application that would need redirects if you want to start the tests just from within the IDE. A big thank you though on LoadFrom vs LoadFile. While it's not answering the questions on how this could be forced, it will be an interesting read.

Comment: Also you should keep a dictionary of assemblies that have already loaded (the actual bytes as byte[])  this way whenever the same assembly gets request again you return return AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Load(assemblyRawBytes);  and when it is not contained they you load it and add it to the dictionary. This will save a lot of problems because you are going to be sure you are loading the assembly only once and sharing it.  Use the assembly name as key.  I do this all the time.  I have many apps that load assemblies from many places including from the internet

Comment: Or ven a dictionary<string,Assembly> would work

Comment: Yes, that's similar to what we're doing in the general handler. But we had one handler left that caused the stackoverflow - and I wanted to write a testcase to make sure it does not happen again;
Similar as we're checkin if an assembly with the same name was already loaded into the appdomain and can just return this one (+ reentry check if we already tried to load it before)